# Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

Hi I copy pasted the sample code of the custom chatter profile page code from the salesforce developer documents to See the look and feel of the page.

But I got the error Message while I preview the VF page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="User"
    extensions="ProfileTabUserController" >

    <apex:outputPanel >

        <p>Your name is {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}, and 
        you're the viewer. Your UID is {!viewerID}.</p>
        <br/>

        <p>You are viewing the profile of {!user.name}, 
        whose UID is {!subjectID}.</p>
        <br/>

        <p>Are you viewing your own profile? {!viewingMyProfile}</p>
        <br/>

    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ProfileTabUserController {
// Purpose: Custom Chatter profile page
private ApexPages.StandardController c;

// Getter methods you can call from your Visualforce page, e.g. {! viewingMyProfile }
public User subjectUser { get; set; }
public boolean viewingMyProfile { get; set; } // Whether or not I’m viewing my profile
public String viewerID { get; set; } // UID string for the viewing user
public String subjectID { get; set; } // UID string for the subject user (being viewed)

// Constructor method for the controller
public ProfileTabUserController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    c = stdController;
    subjectID = getTargetSFDCUID();

    // If we're operating inside a tab running inside of a profile...
    if (subjectID != null) {
        // Inject the sfdc.userId URL parameter value into the id param
        // so the std User controller loads the right User record
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', subjectID);
    }

    // Load the User record for the user whose profile we’re viewing
    this.subjectUser = (User)stdController.getRecord();
    Id viewer = Id.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId());
    Id subject = Id.valueOf(subjectID);
    viewingMyProfile = (viewer == subject);
    viewerID = UserInfo.getUserId();
}

// Fetches URL parameter passed into a profile tab indicating which user is being viewed
private String getTargetSFDCUID() {
    return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.userId');
}
// Overrides StandardController save method to force reload of current page afterwards
public PageReference save() {
    c.save();
    return ApexPages.currentPage();
}

// Overrides StandardController cancel method to force page reload
public PageReference cancel() {
    c.cancel();
    return ApexPages.currentPage();
}}
```

Please find the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: private String getTargetSFDCUID() {
        return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.userId');
    }

This piece of code here is not getting the required parameters.

Comment: There is no error in your code, way your running the code is not proper, that is the reason your getting this error. I have added how to run this page below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line number 33

```
return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.userId');
```

to

```
return UserInfo.getUserId();
```

Code will work perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Do not use Id.valueOf to convert a String to an Id. When the parameter is null, this method throws a NullPointerException. Instead, you should "cast" it (place the desired type in parentheses). This method is null-safe.

---

```
Id viewer = (Id)UserInfo.getUserId();
Id subject = (Id)subjectID;
```

---

Edit: I should mention that you generally do not need to cast between String and Id, as the system will naturally attempt to do so:

```
Id viewer = UserInfo.getUserId();
Id subject = subjectID;
```

However, being explicit is generally considered a good programming habit. A cast isn't just for the compiler, but lets future readers of your code know that you mean to convert the String to an Id.

You generally only need to cast to Id or String if you're using an Object reference to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to know about the profile tab is working with chatter. There is no error in your code , your getting error because way your displaying the page. In order to execute this page you have to do following steps.

### Customize Chatter Profile Pages with Profile Tabs

#### Let Admins Customize Chatter Profile Pages.

> 1. From **Setup**, enter **User Interface** in the Quick Find box,then select **User Interface**.
> 2. Select Enable **Customization of Chatter
>      User Profile Pages**.
> 3. Click **Save**.

#### [Create Visualforce Tabs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_tabs_create.htm&type=0)  for your VF Page.

#### Now you have to add this Vf page into Subtab Apps.

> 1. From **Setup**, enter **Apps** in the Quick Find box, then select Apps.
> 2. You can find **Subtab Apps** section if scroll the page down. 
>      You can find 4 Subtab about Profile. for now you need below two sub tab to be edited to work your code.
>
>    1. **Profile (Others)**  The tabs displayed when users view someone else's profile
>    2. **Profile (Self)**    The tabs displayed when users view their own profile
> 3. Click on **Edit** Profile (Others) and Profile (Self)  You can find
>      your newly created tab in **Available Tabs** , Move your newly
>      created Vf tab from **Available Tabs** to **Selected Tabs**.
> 4. Click **Save**

Now just click **Home tab**. Top you can find Your user Name in top, Click on that. So that it will re direct to your chatter feed.
Inside chatter you can find your sub tab on top click on that, your code runs without any error.

#### Self Profile View

[image: Self Profile View]

#### Others Profile View

[image: Others Profile View]